# How can we calculate the basis for right invariant vector fields from basis left invariant vectr fields

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to calculate the right invariant vector fields from left invariant vector fields. The fact I am using is that for a driftless system $\dot X= XA$ we have $\dot Y= -AY$ where   $Y=inverse Y$